# How to customize Textmate keybindings?

Tags: keyboard, textmate

I'm trying to customize Textmate's keybindings. I edited 'KeyBindings.dict' in Content/Resources/ and then restarted textmate. It does not work.

Is three an easy way to customize keybindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacroMates has an [article](http://manual.macromates.com/en/key_bindings.html) on keybindings for TextMate on their site.